# state.center package in R 3.5

Tags: r, maps

I'm currently using R 3.5 and I need a package state.center for my project. When I try installing it I get the following error message.

```
Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘state.center’ is not available (for R version 3.5.0)
```

Does anyone know how to get around it? (I'm looking for long and lat state data)

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for the `state.center` data set, which is included in the `datasets` package, which in turn is included in base R. So, you should already have it.

`state.center` should show you the data (a list of `x` and `y` positions representing the centre of each state); `?state` will give you more information.